# "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" why?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need this example: random name and random type of test(a1,c3,b2 ...).

```
two.write("%s\n" "%s" % (names.get_first_name(), random.choice(random_list))
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Why?

```
import random
import names
random_list=["a1","a2","a3","b1","b2","b3","c1","c2","c3"]

with open("one.txt","w+") as one, \
     open("two.txt","w+") as two, \
     open("three.txt","w+") as three:
      for i in range(0,3):
          one.write("%s\n" "%s" %  
(names.get_first_name(),random.choice(random_list))
          two.write("%s\n" "%s" % (names.get_first_name(), 
random.choice(random_list))
          three.write("%s\n" "%s" % (names.get_first_name(), 
random.choice(random_list))
```

Comment: You did not close all your brackets `()`

Comment: thaank <3 but result is Harry
b2Rosemary
b3Edward
b1

Comment: why? i need (harry-b2) (rosemary-b3) (edward-b1)

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. Just count the brackets here: `("%s\n" "%s" % (names.get_first_name(), random.choice(random_list))`

Comment: one.txt write this format :
Richard
c1Mary
a3Teresa
a1



and i need this format  (harry-b2) (rosemary-b3) (edward-b1)

Comment: sorry my english

Comment: Your question was about `SyntaxError`. That is caused by the brackets. I guess you are now switching to another question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add an extra bracket at the end of every write call. You have:

```
one.write("%s\n" "%s" %  (names.get_first_name(),random.choice(random_list))
```

But at the end of the line, one of the brackets is from `choice` and the other one from the argument after `%`. You need an extra bracket for the `write` call.

`one.write("%s\n" "%s" %  (names.get_first_name(),random.choice(random_list)))`

**Edit:**

You said:

> but result is Harry b2Rosemary b3Edward b1
>
> i need (harry-b2) (rosemary-b3) (edward-b1)

In the write calls, you put `"%s\n" "%s"`. After the first `%s`, there is a newline, so the name will go on a line, but a newline will be written immediately after it and just then the random number from the list. You need to adjust your template as this: `"%s-%s\n"` or even `"(%s-%s)\n"` if you need the results to be with brackets.

So the final write should be like:
`one.write("%s-%s\n" %  (names.get_first_name(),random.choice(random_list)))`

or

`one.write("(%s-%s)\n" %  (names.get_first_name(),random.choice(random_list)))`

Of course, you need to apply this to all of them.
Cheers!

Comment: yes <3 thank u but result is Harry b2Rosemary b3Edward b1 why? i need (harry-b2) (rosemary-b3) (edward-b1)

Comment: @kkwebba see my updated answer, please.

Comment: very very thank you <3

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. i can not upvote why?

Comment: @kkwebba You need at least 15 reputation to upvote answers. Being active and helping others you'll soon have it :)